# Change variables in guard statement in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image, var

I have a guard statement as shown below that I need for a variable to change if the result is not true

```
func setGif() {
    var animalName = (String(format: "%03d", self.animal.speciesId!))
    guard animal.isDefault! == true else {
        animalName = animalName + "-merg"
        return
    }
    let gif = UIImage(gifName: animalName)
    self.gifIBO.setGifImage(gif, manager: gifManager)
    gifIBO.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.center
}
```

Doing it this way displays the gif for the true value, but not for the false one. I need it to search the gif name with the new value if the guard comes out false. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an inappropriate use of `guard`. `guard` exits the current scope, and you don't want to do that; you want to keep on going. So just use good old `if`. (Also, never compare a Bool to `true` as a condition; a Bool *is* a condition.)

```
if animal.isDefault! {
   // it's true, do one thing
} else {
   // it's false, do a different thing
}
```

In your case, you probably just need the `if`:

```
var animalName = (String(format: "%03d", self.animal.speciesId!))
if !(animal.isDefault!) {
    animalName += "-merg"
}
let gif = UIImage(gifName: animalName)
```

Comment: I see. I wanted to use guard because as the app grows bigger it'll eventually turn into an if else statement and I've been reading that guard is better to avoid if else @matt

Comment: Well, it isn't. And you also seem to think that `guard` is the same as "if not" which is also false.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No need to use guard here. Also use `animal.isDefault == .some(true)` to reduce any chance of crash if isDefault is nil:

```
func setGif() {

    var animalName = (String(format: "%03d", self.animal.speciesId!))
    if animal.isDefault == .some(true) else {
        animalName = animalName + "-merg"
    }

    let gif = UIImage(gifName: animalName)
    self.gifIBO.setGifImage(gif, manager: gifManager)
    gifIBO.contentMode = .center

}
```